# Appending data to existing xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I don't want to overwrite the data in XML File i want to save the old and new data in XML file.

I have a three classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }       

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + " " +LastName + "\t" +Email;
    }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public Student()
    {
    }
    public double AssessmentGrade { get; set; }
    public double AssignmentGrade { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "," +AssessmentGrade + "," + AssignmentGrade;
    }
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "," + RoomNumber;
    }
}
```

I have One more class where i just call the data from PeronDB (Class)

```
public class Persons
{
    private List<Person> persons = null;

      public void Save()
    {
        PersonDB.SavePersons(persons);
    }
 }
```

InPersonDB class I am doing save the whole data in XML File but it overwrite

```
public class PersonDB
{
    private const string path = @"..\..\Persons.xml";


    public static void SavePersons(List<Person> Persons)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = ("   ");

        XmlWriter xmlOut = XmlWriter.Create(path, settings);

        xmlOut.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlOut.WriteStartElement("Persons");

        foreach (Person person in Persons)
        {

                if (typeof(Student).IsInstanceOfType(person))
                {
                    AppendStudentInfo(person, xmlOut);
                }
                else if (typeof(Teacher).IsInstanceOfType(person))
                {
                    AppendTeacherInfo(person, xmlOut);
                }
                else
                {
                    AppendPersonInfo(person, xmlOut);
                }
        }

        xmlOut.WriteEndElement();
        xmlOut.Close();
    }
```

And in the Form_Load event I am doing:

```
    Persons personList = null;

    private void FillPersonlstBox()
    {
        Person p;
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < personList.Count; i++)
        {
            p = personList[i];
            listBox1.Items.Add(p.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HandleChange(personList);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        personList.Changed += new Persons.ChangeHandler(HandleChange);
    }

    private void HandleChange(Persons Persons)
    {
        Persons.Save();
        FillPersonlstBox();
    }

    private void Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        personList.Changed += new Persons.ChangeHandler(HandleChange);
        personList.Fill();
        FillPersonlstBox();
    }
```

When I click the save button, it overwrites the data it delete the old data and saves the new data, Even I press the first Load button and load the data and then add more data after that I save the press button it still overwrite..

Comment: Could you please cut down your sample code to 7-10 lines? It does not look like event handling and other form related code belongs to the question.

Comment: So where's the PersonDB.GetPerson code? How do you know what's changed? Seeing as you are simply recreating the xml from the Persons collection, of course it get's overwritten. So the real question is where the heck did the data you originally loaded get to? Oh and what's with the casting? Each of your classes should have read and writeto xml methods and then get called polymorphically if you are going to do it like this.

Comment: Can you please tell me in brief..I really needs a help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the file path in a constant in PersonDB.  Instead pass make the file path a parameter to Save() and SavePersons().  That way you can prompt the user for a file name and pass it in or have a method generate a name based on a convention.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of changing the signature of SavePersons to include the path as a parameter.

```
public static void SavePersons(List<Person> Persons, String path)
{
//your code
}
```